# NSURL Request is not working

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsurlrequest, tvos

I have a request, after it I need a full Dictionary. But when I checked my request with breakpoints, I saw that it jump over my request... What is wrong in it?

```
  func downloadPackages() {
    let url = "\(URL_BASE)package/list?id=666"
    let dataURL = NSURL(string: url)
    let dataRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: dataURL!)
    let dataSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    print("QQ")
    let dataTask = dataSession.dataTaskWithRequest(dataRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        print("QQ2")

        if error != nil {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        } else {
            do {
                let packageDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                if let results = packageDict!["data"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                    for obj in results {
                        let package = Package(packageDict: obj)
                        print(self.monsters.count)
                        self.monsters.append(package)

                    }
                }
                //Main UI thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            catch {
            }
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

It doesn't print ("QQ2"), but it prints ("QQ").

Comment: This is an asynchronous request. Did you wait for it to finish?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you didn't add HTTP Request methods and values. So try like this :-

```
func downloadPackages() {
    let url = "\(URL_BASE)package/list?id=666"
    let dataURL = NSURL(string: url)
    let dataRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: dataURL!)
    dataRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    dataRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    dataRequest.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let dataSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    print("QQ")
    let dataTask = dataSession.dataTaskWithRequest(dataRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        print("QQ2")

        if error != nil {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        } else {
            do {
                let packageDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                if let results = packageDict!["data"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                    for obj in results {
                        let package = Package(packageDict: obj)
                        print(self.monsters.count)
                        self.monsters.append(package)

                    }
                }
                //Main UI thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
               }
            }
            catch {
            }
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you made a syntax mistake:-

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
               })
```

and yes wait for a sec for uitableview to be populated.

Following would be better way:-

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
 for obj in results {
                        let package = Package(packageDict: obj)
                        print(self.monsters.count)
                        self.monsters.append(package)

                    }
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
               })
})
```

rest seems to be fine.

Comment: one more thing just open the url in browser with required parameters and check whether its giving the expected response. because it should print QQ2